# Space opera I read before 2004. Egg shaped car, wormhole, biblical story arc , father-son reunited

Tags: story-identification

So I read this book before 2004 and it was already in tatters (borrowed). It was a space opera involving a moon base, a spaceship fight, a wormhole, the crash landing of a ship, an alternate earth with egg shaped cars that fixed themselves, and a biblical story arc (Cain and Abel).

Comment: What is a "spaceship fight"? Two crewmen in a fistfight on a spaceship? A space battle between two fleets of spaceships?

Comment: The title mentions a father-son reunion but there's nothing about that in the actual question.